# How to create CVS branch from old data

Tags: branch, cvs

I need to create CVS branch from old version of main. Is it possible to checkout data from main branch by date and create branch tag on it? Would sticky tag cause problem ?

```
cvs -z1 co -D "2018-04-16 05:42:14 PDT"  -P <module>
cvs tag -b <branch_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not test what you are suggesting, but it looks perfectly OK.

Sticky tag should not cause any trouble with creation of a branch, since in any case CVS tracks changes on a file-by-file basis, so a creating a branch simply saves all file revisions for the current module as the basis for the branch.
Note that you need to checkout the branch to start working on it. You can use:

```
cvs update -r <branch_name>
```

after branch is created.